# Поиск максимального значения в коллекции List<>

Tags: c#

Написал вот такой код:

```
private static float Calc(Node node)
    {
      var p = 0f;
      foreach (var n in node.Linked)
          p = node.Linked.Max(z => Calc(n));

      return p;
    }
```

Значение элементов коллекции либо 0 либо 1, но при любых входных значениях я получаю всегда 0, подскажите в чём проблема?

Comment: Ваша функция `Calc` нигде не возвращает `1`.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю среди аргументов выбирается максимальный элемент записывается в p и в место вызова возвращает p? я не прав?

Comment: Вчитайтесь, пожалуйста, в мой первый комментарий. "И внял я неба содроганье,
И горний ангелов полет,
И гад морских подводный ход,
И дольней лозы прозябанье." Пушкин

Comment: Место вызова функции?

Comment: Что значат эти три слова?

Comment: Участок кода в который я делаю запрос на расчёт это функции.

Comment: Слов стало больше, но смысла не прибавилось :). Вам понятен мой первый комментарий?

Comment: Не очень понятно.